# Loss function in tensorflow sensitive to type of classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am interested in using a custom loss function in tensorflow that takes the type of error into account. For example, I would like to create a function that weighs some type of error (predicting class 1 with label being class 3) more heavily than others (predicting class 2 with label being class 3). The reason stems from a current project I'm working on, where the classes are clearly ranked (although only on an ordinal scale).

I have implemented a loss function similarly to the one shown in (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115#issuecomment-204060456) using Keras. However, I would like to know how I can implement something similar directly in tensorflow. Currently, I have unfortunately had no luck. I tried using it more or less in its current from in tensorflow (calling the K. parts with tf.keras.backend), but had no luck (see code chunk 1). I also tried writing something similar with matrix  multiplication (using tf.matmul), but then my error diverged (see code chunk 2). Note that Omega is a K x K matrix with weigths.

For K classes, I would like there to be a total of K^2 different weights, accounting for every type of classification and misclassification.

Any help is greatly appreciated! This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, so if I have done anything wrong be sure to let me know.

Code 1:

```
number_of_classes = 3
modifier = tf.keras.backend.zeros_like(output_softmax[:, 0])
y_pred_max = tf.keras.backend.max(output_softmax, axis = 1)
y_pred_max = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(y_pred_max, 1)
y_pred_max_mat = tf.keras.backend.equal(output_softmax, y_pred_max)
for i, j in product(range(number_of_classes), range(number_of_classes)):
    modifier += (tf.keras.backend.cast(Omega[j, i], tf.keras.backend.floatx()) *
                 tf.keras.backend.cast(y_pred_max_mat[:, i], tf.keras.backend.floatx()) * tf.keras.backend.cast(y_[:, j], tf.keras.backend.floatx()))
loss =  tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(output_softmax, y_) * modifier
```

Problem: Now my loss for a given epoch isn't a number, but rather a matrix. When checking for early stopping (I track the loss for each epoch, and compare the current loss with the minimum loss), the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

Code 2:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels = y_, logits = output))
mod_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(loss, tf.matmul(tf.matmul(y_, Omega), output_softmax, transpose_b=True)))
```

Problem: Now my loss increases over time.

Comment: You write that you "tried using it more or less in its current from in tensorflow". Can you please show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: I have added the code as you suggested as well as the code when using matrix operations. Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I will mark as solved when I can (need to wait 5 hours).